# security captcha image not dispalyiing in 000webhost

Tags: php

I have uploaded my website on 000webhost but in my registration form the security captcha image is not displaying while it is displaying in my localhost.

My captcha code is:

```
<?php
include_once('includes/session.php');
$_SESSION['secure']=rand(1000,9999);
header('content-type:image/jpeg');
$text=$_SESSION['secure'];
$font_size=25;
$image_width=200;
$image_height=40;
$image=imagecreate($image_width,$image_height);
imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);
$text_color=imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
for($x=1;$x<=40;$x++)
{$x1=rand(1,120);
$x2=rand(1,120);
$y1=rand(1,120);
$y2=rand(1,120);
imageline($image,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$text_color);    
}
imagettftext($image,$font_size,0,15,30,$text_color,'MAGNETOB.TTF',$text);
imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

And I'm displaying captcha as:

```
<img src="captcha1.php" id="captcha" />
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Try to see the picture's source code with a text editor. I'm pretty sure there's a PHP error message showing up there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you activated the GD extension ?